# Why does NBA 2K11 crash when I play My Player mode?

Tags: nintendo-wii, nba2k11

I was playing My Player, and when I tried to play the next game my Wii suddenly crashed with a buzzing sound. I reset the game, loaded my player again and tried to play the next game and it still crashes.

Based on my searches in the web, here are some things worth mentioning:

- tried registering and posting to 2k11 forums but after activating I can't post a single thread. It says I don't have permission
- tried http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/987827-/56804773 loaded my player, deleted the save file and saved again then played the next game: freeze
- load the game, play a Jordan Challenge (3-5 possessions), quit, load my player, play the next game: freeze
- load the game, load my player, do a scrimmage(don't have any drills left) and play next game: freeze
- load the game, changed the game mode to default, play the next game: freeze

What else could I do? Can anyone point me in the right direction? This is pretty frustrating as I have been playing all the games (no sim) and I am at my first season 46 games in.

The game freezes with a buzzing sound as soon as I hit the play the next game button. Any advice or links will be appreciated.